# Jenkins repeating initial setup again and again

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-run

Jenkins is being run by me in Google Cloud Run, a serverless service, with a configuration of 8 GB and 2 CPU. I'm having trouble with the initial setup. I can run Jenkins's initial setup and sign in to the dashboard, but after a short while, it keeps returning me to the initial setup. I'm a newbie in Jenkins and really appreciate the suggestions on how to overcome this issue